# ¿Como solucionar error expection in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.nullpointerException?

Tags: java

Tengo un programa que le quiero cambiar el icono (en vez de la taza de cafe) a una imagen que tengo en ruta pero al momento de agregar la linea 27 me manda un error, espero que me ayuden gracias[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podria ser por la ruta de la imagen, recuerdo que en NetBeans hay que usar doble diagonal //.

Answer (score 0):

El codigo que empleastes para buscar el recurso de imagen se usa cuando la misma se encuentra dentro de tu proyecto o paquete.
Viendo que la imagen es externa, dentro de un directorio fuera de tu proyecto te sugiero aplicar lo siguiente.

```
ImageIcon icono =  new ImageIcon(new File("/home/andy/Imágenes/407463-PD558O-40.jpg").toURI().toURL());
```

Tambien se puede utilizar este algoritmo en el constructor del Jframe

```
 setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().
            getImage(getClass().getResource("recursos/icono.png"))
        );
```

El resultado actual sera que el icono se mostrara en la barra de aplicaciones cuando se ejecute.
Otra opcion es cambiar todo el tema con NimRODTheme que permite customizar todo. Para ello hay que descargar sus librerias.
Ejm para el codigo del main del JFrame

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        NimRODTheme nt = new NimRODTheme();
        nt.setPrimary(new Color(153, 244, 51));
        nt.setPrimary1(new Color(133, 224, 31));
        nt.setPrimary2(new Color(143, 234, 41));
        nt.setPrimary3(new Color(153, 244, 51));
        nt.setSecondary(new Color(222, 230, 250));
        nt.setSecondary1(new Color(202, 210, 230));
        nt.setSecondary2(new Color(212, 220, 240));
        nt.setSecondary3(new Color(222, 230, 250));
        nt.setMenuOpacity(20);
        nt.setFrameOpacity(20);
        nt.setOpacity(20);
        NimRODLookAndFeel NimRODLF = new NimRODLookAndFeel();
        NimRODLF.setCurrentTheme(nt);
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(NimRODLF);
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new PRINCIPAL().setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PRINCIPAL.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya agregue esta linea de codigo
ImageIcon icono =  new ImageIcon(new File("/home/andy/Imágenes/407463-PD558O-40.jpg").toURI().toURL());
y ya no me marca error pero no me muestra la imagen como icono y ya comprobe la ruta

Comment: Recuerda que debes cambiar la ruta de la imagen segun donde tu la tengas guardada. Por que la mostrada tiene la ruta de mi pc....!!!! ajusta eso y me cuentas

Comment: Si puse la ruta de la imagen y no sirve

Comment: Revisa que las dimensiones del icono sea 16x16, 32x32, 64x64 y 128x128

Comment: ¿En que extension debe de estar?, la que estoy usando es .png